# CSS animation opacity(0) goes back to 1

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm using a `@keyframes` to go from 0% to 50% to 100%.
During the percentages I want to change the behaviour of the svg element.

```
@keyframes scale {
0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
50% {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
100% {
    opacity:0;
}
}

.head_top{ 
    animation: scale 1s ease-in-out 1 backwards;
}
```

SVG element:

```
<g><!-- HEAD TOP -->
    <path class="head_top" d="M381,230.571h.008A191.367,191.367,0,0,1,555.278,342.83a177.166,177.166,0,1,0-348.555,0A191.373,191.373,0,0,1,381,230.571Z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="5"/>
</g>
```

So the element goes at 0% to 50% from a `scale(0)` to a `scale(1)`
from 50% to 100% the `opacity` goes to 0.
This all works. However after the `opacity(0)` is reached the element goes back to visible.

I think I'm missing something in my `@keyframes` but can't figure out what!

-----------UPDATE------------
I must be some kind of special stupid but I use the following.

```
@keyframes fadeout {
0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    opacity:0;
}
50% {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    opacity:1;
}
100% {
    opacity:0;
}
}
.chin{ 
    animation: fadeout 1s ease-in-out 1 forwards; animation-delay: 2s;  
}
```

With this SVG:

```
<g><!-- CHIN -->
    <circle class="chin" cx="414.4" cy="545.4" r="109.5" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="5.012"/>
</g>
```

The circle is supposed to go from `opacity:0;` and `scale:0;` to 1.
But at the first frame the circle is fully visible! After that the animation starts and works.
Why is the circle visible on the first frame?

Comment: did you try `0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    opacity: 0;}`

Comment: Well it's what `backwards` [fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode#Values) does. Did you mean `forwards`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[animation-fill-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode):forwards; would seem to be what you're looking for.

> The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution.

You can set it in the shorthand where it would replace the backwards keyword that you currently have.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@keyframes scale {
0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
50% {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
100% {
    opacity:0;
}
}

.head_top{ 
    animation: scale 1s ease-in-out 1 forwards;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <g><!-- HEAD TOP -->
    <path class="head_top" d="M381,230.571h.008A191.367,191.367,0,0,1,555.278,342.83a177.166,177.166,0,1,0-348.555,0A191.373,191.373,0,0,1,381,230.571Z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="5"/>
</g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: That worked. Great. Can you please tell me why? I would like to understand!

Comment: there's a link in the answer for further reading, does that not explain things sufficiently?

Comment: Sorry missed that. I'll read up. ThnQ

Comment: nice, works fine for me in my ionic 5 apps..Thanks